# Effective vs Super Effective move (Pokemon gen 8)

Tags: pokemon-sword-shield, pokemon-eighth-generation

In Pokemon Sword, when you use a move sometimes it tells you under the move is "effective" or "super effective" under the move:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXmzD.png]

Super effective I know doubles damage for every type that it's super effective against (4x if super effective on a dual Pokemon). However, regular effective doesn't actually seem to do anything.

Is this a bug?

Comment: What made you think it's doing nothing?

Comment: @Skye-AT because the move does the same damage as if nothing was below the move.

Answer (score 10):

"Effective" just means it will take regular effect, and do normal damage.

The levels are:

- Super effective (4x), if super effective against both types
- Super effective (2x)
- Effective (1x)
- Not very effective (0.5x)
- Not very effective (0.25x), if not very effective against both types
- No effect (0x)

Comment: Since the question title mentions "gen 8" and not "sword/shield" specifically, it might be worth noting that the multipliers are different in Legends Arceus: they're 2.5×, 2×, 1×, 0.5×, 0.4×, and 0× respectively. It's also possible, with the move Forest's Curse, to have a triple weakness in sword/shield, which works out to 8× damage. I believe--though I haven't worked out the exact type combo needed--that Forest's Curse and Trick-or-Treat can also give a triple resistance, which likewise works out to 0.125× damage.

Comment: @Hearth Sizzlipede is fire/bug and Snom is ice/bug and both get x0.25 against grass, adding grass type will make a x0.125 modifier